# Checking if Table A contains Table B

Tags: algorithm, scilab

I am a beginner in programming, especially in Scilab.

I need your help to write this short algorithm:

We have 2, **sorted, non-decreasing** tables A=[1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,8,10] and B=[2,2,3,4,4,4].
Table A will always be **bigger** then Table B.
I need your help constructing The algorytm for checking whether the table B is contained entirely in the table A (without violating the order of the elements of the B array).

So for tables A=[1,2,***2,2,3,4,4,4***,5,8,10] and B=[***2,2,3,4,4,4***] the condition is met.

i have this for now

```
function sprawdz (A,B, n, m)
A=[2 3 0 5 1 1 2]
B=[3 0 5 1]
n=length(A)
m=length(B)
i=1
j=1
while (i<n && j<m)
    if A(i)==B(j) then
        i=i+1
        j=j+1
        if (j==m) then
             return %t
             break
        end
    else 
        i=i+1
        j=1
    end
end
return %f
if sprawdz (A,B, n, m) == %t then
    disp("spoko")
else 
    disp("nie")
end
```

endfunction

Comment: If both are ordered the "without violating the order of the elements of the B array" is always true if A contains B.

Comment: Try a `for`-loop iterating on the indices of `A`: `for i=1:length(A)`. Inside the `for`-loop, maintain a variable `j` corresponding to indices in `B`. When A(i) == B(j), increment j. When A(i) < B(j), do not increment j. When A(i) > B(j), halt and return False. When j > length(B), halt and return True.

Comment: @Stef Oh I see, my bad, I mistakenly thought you were traversing B as well in each loop with a quick glance. I will remove my comments.

Comment: I deleted my answer as what @Stef proposed is much faster, practical and easier solution, although the solutions I proposed achieve the end result, the naive approach here in the Stef 's comment is as fast as others and also easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

In Scilab language, we can simply write `vectorfind(A,B)` that returns all positions in A where B is met and starts:

```
--> A = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,8,10], B = [2,2,3,4,4,4]
 A  = 
   1.   2.   2.   2.   3.   4.   4.   4.   5.   8.   10.
 B  = 
   2.   2.   3.   4.   4.   4.
--> vectorfind(A, B)
 ans  =
   3.
```

`vectorfind()` does not require from `A` or/and `B` to be sorted.
In addition, it can work with some wildcards. `A` is an array with any number of dimensions: 1D (vector), 2D (matrix), 3D, .. ND

If you just need a boolean answer:

`vectorfind(A,B)<>[]`

For illustrated examples or more information: https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/vectorfind.html

Answer (score 0):

below code checks if an array contains all elements in another array:

```
public static boolean linearIn(Integer[] outer, Integer[] inner) {

   return Arrays.asList(outer).containsAll(Arrays.asList(inner));
}
```

In your case there will be your two array

> Another approch if you want to check contiguous subsequence
> Simple Approach:

A simple approach is to run two nested loops and generate all subarrays of the array A[] and use one more loop to check if any of the subarray of A[] is equal to the array B[].

- Efficient Approach :

An efficient approach is to use two pointers to traverse both the array simultaneously. Keep the pointer of array B[] still and if any element of A[] matches with the first element of B[] then increase the pointer of both the array else set the pointer of A to the next element of the previous starting point and reset the pointer of B to 0. If all the elements of B are matched then print YES otherwise print NO.

> Below is the implementation of the above approach:

class SubTable
{

```
    // Function to check if an array is subarray of another array
    static boolean isSubArray(int A[], int B[],
                                   int n, int m)
    {
        // Two pointers to traverse the arrays
        int i = 0, j = 0;
     
        // Traverse both arrays simultaneously
        while (i < n && j < m)
        {
     
            // If element matches
            // increment both pointers
            if (A[i] == B[j])
            {
     
                i++;
                j++;
     
                // If array B is completely
                // traversed
                if (j == m)
                    return true;
            }
             
            // If not,
            // increment i and reset j
            else
            {
                i = i - j + 1;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
     
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        int A[] = { 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2 };
        int n = A.length;
        int B[] = { 3, 0, 5, 1 };
        int m = B.length;
     
        if (isSubArray(A, B, n, m))
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"A simple approach is to run two nested loops and generate all subarrays of the array A[] and use one more loop to check if any of the subarray of A[] is equal to the array B[]."* Hmm, how do you propose to do that? Note that we want to check whether B is a subsequence of A. Not necessarily a contiguous subsequence. See [Difference : subsequences and substrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237097/difference-subsequences-and-substrings)

Comment: right! above solution will only check contiguous subsequence.

Comment: I have added another code at top

Comment: Hey @Vaibhavv 
thanks for helping me.
Could you transform it from java to scilab? I am having troubles with it

Comment: i have this for now
`function sprawdz (A,B, n, m)
    A=[2 3 0 5 1 1 2]
    B=[3 0 5 1]
    n=length(A)
    m=length(B)
    i=1
    j=1
    while (i<n && j<m)
        if A(i)==B(j) then
            i=i+1
            j=j+1
            if (j==m) then
                 return %t
                 break
            end
        else 
            i=i+1
            j=1
        end
    end
    return %f
    if sprawdz (A,B, n, m) == %t then
        disp("spoko")
    else 
        disp("nie")
    end
endfunction
`

Comment: sure, what ever I found it would help you see these two links: https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/vectorfind.html  and https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/m2sci_ismember.html